# Correct way to enable import of all submodule in python package

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm making a python package using setuptools, and I'm having trouble making all nested folders in my source code available for import after installing the package. The directory I'm working in has a structcure like illustrated below.

```
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── foo
        ├── a
        │   ├── aa
        │   │   └── aafile.py
        │   └── afile.py
        ├── b
        │   └── bfile.py
        └── __init__.py
```

Currently, I can't import submodules, such as `from foo.a import aa` or `from foo.a.aa import some_method`, unless I explicitly pass the names of the submodules to setuptools. That is, setup.py needs to contain something like

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    version="0.0.1",
    name="foo",
    py_modules=["foo", "foo.a", "foo.a.a", "foo.b"],
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=["foo", "foo.a", "foo.a.a", "foo.b"],
    include_package_data=True,
    #  more arguments go here
)
```

This makes organizing the code pretty cumbersome. Is there a simple way to just allows users of the package to install any submodule contained in src/foo?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want [`setuptools.find_packages()`](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#finding-simple-packages) – though all in all, you might want to consider tossing `setup.py` altogether in favor of a PEP 517 style build with no arbitrary Python [but just `pyproject.toml` (and possibly `setup.cfg`)](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#basic-use).

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    version="0.0.1",
    name="foo",
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=find_packages(where='src'),
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

Comment: How do you do something analogous to what you described above but using the non-deprecated pyproject.toml instead of setup.py?

Comment: @MaileCupo I'd recommend `hatch` for your PEP517 packager; it does this automatically.

Comment: Looks like thats well documented here: https://hatch.pypa.io/latest/config/build/ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Every package/subpackage must contain a (at least empty) `__init__.py` file to be considered so.

If you want to the whole package&subpackages tree to be imported with just one `import foo` consider filling your `__init__.py` files with the import of the relative subpackages.

```py
# src/foo/__init__.py

import foo.a
import foo.b
```

```py
# src/foo/a/__init__.py

import foo.a.aa
```

```py
# src/foo/b/__init__.py

import foo.b.bb
```

Otherwise leave the `__init__.py` files empty and the user will need to manually load the subpackag/submodule he wants.

Answer (score 0):

[Using setup.py is legitimate and not deprecated](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/setup-py-deprecated/) as wrongly suggested in comments.

Likewise, the right solution is different from what answers proposed. The first answer fails to find anything because the top module is a namespace package.

The correct way is to **properly annotate modules, namespace packages, data files** and **use the proper tool for packages discovery or comply with a supported layout such as "src"**.

Consider this structure (fix: added missing `__init__.py` to annotate `aa` module).

```bash
tmp
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┗ foo
 ┃ ┃ ┣ a
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ aa
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ aa_file.py
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ afile.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗ b
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ bfile.py
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ config.yaml
 ┗ setup.py
```

Note that both `foo` and `foo/a` are [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#native-namespace-packages) and will not be found by `find_packages`. Note that I also added config file as an example of essential non-Pythonic files.This is the right installation setup:

```py
# setup.py

from setuptools import setup, find_packages, find_namespace_packages

setup(name='proper-package',
      version='0.1',
      description='A demo showing a proper setup for a complex package.',
      packages = find_namespace_packages(where="src"), # NOTE: better than <find_packages> which ignores namespace packages and their nested modules!
      package_dir={'':'src'},
      include_package_data=True,
      package_data={"": ["*.yaml"]}, # NOTE: use this for non-pythonic files needed, such as configs, demo data etc...
)
```

The installation with `pip install .` fired from the `project` directory generates the `build` folder as the intermediate step and eventually the expected content under `lib/python3.x/site-packages`:

```bash
foo
 ┣ a
 ┃ ┣ __pycache__
 ┃ ┃ ┗ afile.cpython-310.pyc
 ┃ ┣ aa
 ┃ ┃ ┣ __pycache__
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.cpython-310.pyc
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ aa_file.cpython-310.pyc
 ┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┃ ┗ aa_file.py
 ┃ ┗ afile.py
 ┗ b
 ┃ ┣ __pycache__
 ┃ ┃ ┣ __init__.cpython-310.pyc
 ┃ ┃ ┗ bfile.cpython-310.pyc
 ┃ ┣ __init__.py
 ┃ ┣ bfile.py
 ┃ ┗ config.yaml
```